# Can you turn off reCAPTCHA step in Firebase phone verification on Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter web app that uses Firebase for authentication. I am making user's verify their phone numbers by temporarily linking the number to their account using the `linkWithPhoneNumber` method.

The issue is that the reCAPTCHA window is always shown. I want it to NEVER show but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that on Flutter web.

[image]

[Here are the Flutter Firebase web auth docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth#web_signinwithphonenumber).

My code:

```dart
Future<void> sendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber) async {
    String linkNumber = '+$phoneNumber';

    try {
      confirmationResult = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.linkWithPhoneNumber(linkNumber);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error sending verification code: $e');

      await handleError(e);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

I've seen a few posts that suggest ways of turning this off but they either only work during testing or on native platforms. For example, you can disable the reCAPTCHA during testing using the FirebaseAuth settings:

```
await _firebaseAuth.setSettings(appVerificationDisabledForTesting: true);
```

### More Info

After some more research, I'm not sure how many people will see this. In the [Firebase reCAPTCHA docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#set-up-the-recaptcha-verifier), it says this:

> The RecaptchaVerifier object supports invisible reCAPTCHA, which can often verify the user without requiring any user action, as well as the reCAPTCHA widget, which always requires user interaction to complete successfully.